# Get makefile directory

Tags: makefile

I am distributing my cpp files along with a makefile. Now the makefile is located in the same directory as the cpp file.

What is the variable (if any) in makefile that allows me to retrieve the current directory where the makefile is located? In this way I can use that variable to specify my cpp path for compilation.

My makefile is as follows:

```
all:
    g++ ($makeFileDir)/main.cpp ($makeFileDir)/hello.cpp ($makeFileDir)/factorial.cpp -o ($makeFileDir)/hello.exe
```

**Edit: I am running my makefiles on Windows**

Comment: The "location" of a file is a weird concept.  Remember that a given file can have many names (hard links, even in windows).  Also, you're mixing in another concept; the "current" directory usually means something special, and isn't related to any individual file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I remember I had the exact same problem. It's not possible, as far as I remember. 
The best bet you can have is to pass it as a variable. That is both cross platform and guaranteed to work, as you know the makefile dir at invoke time (otherwise you can't invoke it).

In alternative, you can do a very dirty trick, meaning you try to combine your current path (you can obtain with $(CURDIR) in gnu make) with the path of the invocation of the makefile (which can be tricky, and depends on your make)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a cross-platform way to get the directory of the Makefile, which should be fully shell-agnostic.

```
makeFileDir := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
```

Note that this will give you the directory of the *Makefile being currently interpreted*. You might have bad (or good!) surprises if you include a Malefile using this statement from another.

That should be enough if you use a recent implementation of make for windows, i.e. [Chocolatey's](https://chocolatey.org/packages/make).

#### Issues with older make for Windows

Depending on the version of make you're using on Windows, there can be inconsistencies in the handling of backslashes. You might need one of the following variant. That's the case for [GnuWin's make 3.81 binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) for example.

- *Make the path separator consistent*. The statement below uses forward slashes only, just swap `\` and `/` to get the opposite behavior. From my experience (with GnuWin's make), you might have to use forward slashes to use such a variable for make `include` statements or to use it in `VPATH`.
  But you would of course need backslashes in the DOS shell, and therefore in recipes... You might need two versions of the variable, but at least the substitution makes sure that the path separator is consistent!

```
makeFileDir := $(subst \,/,$(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))
```

- The `abspath` function of GnuWin make 3.81 is broken and doesn't handle paths with drive letters in it. Here is a workaround to handle Windows absolute paths (with drive letter) as well. You can then use it to get the directory of the Makefile (here with the path separator substitution as well).
  I won't explain the details, but the workaround simply returns the argument if that's already a Windows absolute path, i.e. if there is `:` in the root of the path, and uses the builtin `abspath` otherwise.

```
define fixabspath
$(if $(findstring :,$(firstword $(subst /, ,$(subst \,/,$(1))))),$\$
$(1),$\
$(abspath $(1)))

makeFileDir := $(subst \,/,$(dir $(call fixabspath,$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))))
```

*Remarks*

- There might be sources I'm omitting here and I'm sorry for that. It's been a long time ago.
- In the `fixabspath` definition, `$\` are just here to split the line for readability.
- The `MAKEFILE_LIST` variable contains a list of the Makefiles being interpreted, the last one being the current one. See the corresponding [manual page](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.80/html_node/make_17.html).
- If I remember correctly, this also works with macOS' native make.

Answer (score 1):

For 'cygwin' and 'linux' use I've solves this by calling pwd directly from the rule in the makefile:

```
do.%: %.cpp
  echo "Running command in " `pwd`
  somecommand $^
```

Comment: The current working directory isn't the same thing as the directory the makefile is in.  (do a "cd /fnord; make -f /foo/bar/Makefile" in your head and you'll realize the problem)

Answer (score 0):

you can use $(srcdir)

then ./configure --srcdir="/your/path/to/the/source/directory"

Comment: This assumes Graviton is using Autoconf, which isn't necessarily a good assumption.